# Export scrapy as csv without header every re-running

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my code:

## items.py

```
from scrapy import Item, Field
class NetmallScrapyItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    phoneNum = Field()
    workTime = Field()
```

## spider.py

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from Netmall_Scrapy.items import NetmallScrapyItem

class FukuikitaSpider(Spider):
    name = 'FukuiKita'
    allowed_domains = ['netmall.hardoff.co.jp/shop/201087']
    start_urls = ['http://netmall.hardoff.co.jp/shop/201087/']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = NetmallScrapyItem()
        item['phoneNum'] = response.xpath(".//span[@class='u-pc']/text()").extract_first()
        item['workTime'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='p-dispShop__contact']/p[2]/text()").extract_first()
        return item
```

## my output file

```
phoneNum,workTime
電話 0776-57-0077,営業時間 10:00～20:00
phoneNum,workTime
電話 0776-57-0077,営業時間 10:00～20:00
```

So, please help me to make my output csv like below:

```
phoneNum,workTime
電話 0776-57-0077,営業時間 10:00～20:00
電話 0776-57-0077,営業時間 10:00～20:00
```

BTW could you guys show me the best way to store data. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can create your own item exporter for that, because what scrapy's in-built csv exporter does is it writes the header as many time you run the spider again. but I would not suggest you to do that because in that case your exporter has to read that file everytime before the write happens. You can checkout https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter and try to extend it if you want

Comment: Sorry for very late reply. Thank you very much. I've managed the problem.